# RecyclerView textChangeListener or databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I've got a `RecylerView` where each row has an `EditText`. This `EditText` is for the user to input player names. When the user inputs the names I need the list which the `Adapter` is looking at to update, in one way or another.

First I thought I would just put an `textChangedListener` on the `EditText` , which partly works. **The problem is when the user adds a new row or removes a row, it seems like the listeners for each `EditText` gets called when calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` .** `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called from the `textChangedListener` as well, giving the error

```
Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.
```

**Another option** is to not use a `textChangedListener` but rather only update the adapter list whenever the user adds a row, removes a row or begins the game. But for this I somehow need to fetch the information from all the editTexts present in the RecyclerView, and I haven't found a way to do so. If this is possible I could simply clear the adapter list and replace with whatever the user has put into the recyclerView each time `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

**Third option** would be to use `data binding`. I've been trying to follow guides but haven't got it to work. Binding would have to make the editTexts update the adapter list directly, and preferably update the `EditText` when the list is changed but that's not as important.

Any ideas on how to best implement this?

```
public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReviewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> data;

public ReviewAdapter(ArrayList<String> data) {

    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context c = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.txtPlayerName.setText(data.get(position));
    holder.txtRowNumber.setText(position+1 + "");
    holder.btnRemoveRow.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(position, holder.btnRemoveRow));
    holder.txtPlayerName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int pos;
    Button button;


    public MyClickListener(int _pos, Button _button) {
        super();
        pos = _pos;
        button = _button;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        data.remove(pos);
        System.out.println("MyClickListener.onClick.pos: " + pos);
        MainActivity.txtPlayers.setText(data.size() + " players");
        ReviewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    int pos;

    public MyTextWatcher(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        data.set(pos, s.toString());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    EditText txtPlayerName;
    TextView txtRowNumber;
    Button btnRemoveRow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        txtPlayerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        txtRowNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        btnRemoveRow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What have yoyu done so far show us some code also your expected output and actual output

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I added the code for my adapter. I don't have much of an actual output except for the specified error I wrote above, which I get if I have a textWatcher that calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If I don't use a textWatcher the adapter list simply doesn't update based on user input (as I want it to do), since I haven't implemented data binding or figured out how to fetch information directly from the recyclerView.

Comment: do you really want to save data at each character changed or after text changed?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I could definitely put the code in `afterTextChanged()`, but for the moment that's not what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: ok check my code below. changed your adapter code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified and minified your Adapter class. Never assign `onClickListener` inside `onBindViewHolder` instead of that class you can use this one this may solve your issue.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReviewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private Context mContext;

    public ReviewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txtPlayerName.setText(data.get(position));
        holder.txtRowNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher {

        EditText txtPlayerName;
        TextView txtRowNumber;
        Button btnRemoveRow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            txtPlayerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            txtRowNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
            btnRemoveRow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
            btnRemoveRow.setOnClickListener(this);
            txtPlayerName.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == btnRemoveRow) {
                data.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                System.out.println("MyClickListener.onClick.pos: " + getAdapterPosition());
                MainActivity.txtPlayers.setText(data.size() + " players");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            data.set(getAdapterPosition(), s.toString());
            //notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing your code but I still get the same error. This is the full stack trace... Edit: Nevermind full stack trace was too long haha, but  this is the gist of it: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. It's referring to -_notifyItemChanged()_ inside _onTextChanged()_

Comment: move this line `notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());` to `afterTextChanged()` also i don't think u need to use this line cause it set new data to editext while your edittext has the latest changes. only `data.set(getAdapterPosition(), s.toString());` is enough

Comment: Moving the line to `afterTextChanged()` doesn't fix it, however as you suggested removing `notifyItemChanged()` solves everything. Thank you! I tried doing that in my initial adapter as well, and only doing `data.set(pos, s.toString());', but in my case that didn't work. Any chance you can point out what makes it work in your code but not in mine?

Comment: your are assigning text watcher in onBind() thats the main i9ssI'm not sure about that but the way youn assigned `OnClicklistener` and `TextChangedListener` is totally incorrect creates performance issue. Always assign that in `Viewholder` and for position call `getAdapterPosition()` in `ViewHolder`

Comment: Got it. Thank you again!

Comment: getAdapterPosition problem solved thank u

Answer (score 0):

in adapter implements View.OnFocusChangeListener

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position) {
editText.setText(model.getValue());
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
editText.setTag(position);
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if (v.getTag() == null)
    return;
int position = (int) v.getTag();
if (!hasFocus && v instanceof EditText)
    mValues.get(position).setValue(((EditText) v).getText().toString());
}
```